# incompatible character encodings

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, rack

In normal way the request is coming like this way

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "status_id"=>"12686"}
```

other than, from one client the requst coming like this way

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"\xE2??", "status_id"=>"12686"}
```

So this time i am getting this error
"ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT)", from client browser, so i am bit confused, where this is happening actually, one place is

```
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => 
    session_path(resource_name), html: { class: "signup" }) do |f| %>
```

is there any issues with clients browser? in these two statements, what will be the most change to occur this?

will this solution [Ruby on Rails "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" due to bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648206/ruby-on-rails-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-due-to-bot) solve this problem?

Comment: Is it just one client with this error or everybody?

Comment: Yes this is happening only from one client at night

Answer (score 0):

If it is not happening to all of your users and from your comment it seems to be a single client at night, then I wouldn't worry about it.

From your log message, it is clear that the "client" does not support utf-8 encoding. Most probably it is some crawler.

Since it is client side support, there is not much you can do about it. So don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, in the log it shows like this also cache error: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Comment: will this solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648206/ruby-on-rails-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-due-to-bot?

Comment: That might help, but I'd prefer to see them in my logs and know about them.