# Unexpected error while processing request: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 #

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when enable rack-mini-profiler gem, it gives error

```
Unexpected error while processing request: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

using

```
 Rails v4.0.6

 rack-mini-profiler 0.10.1

 Ruby 2.2.0
```

only happen if enable rake-mini-profiler, otherwise application working fine.

backtrace:

```
Unexpected error while processing request: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.1/lib/mini_profiler/client_settings.rb:24:in `split'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.1/lib/mini_profiler/client_settings.rb:24:in `initialize'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.1/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:153:in `new'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.1/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:153:in `call'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run_machine'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
/home/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure, i think this error keep coming after 'Slim-Rails' gem

Answer (score 0):

just added

```
gem "handle_invalid_percent_encoding_requests"
```

working fine !

solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24894410/3212137