# Rails - render static html page from middleware

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rack-middleware

Yesterday my application was visited by yandex bot with an invalid URL

```
/restday?biG%D9%02
```

and for this application is throwing an error

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

I need to render 400.html static page with status 400 instead of 404 whenever there is a invalid character error. I followed the solutions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648206/ruby-on-rails-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-due-to-bot) and [rack-robustness gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611841/mysterious-rails-error-with-almost-no-trace/24637719#24637719) but it doesn't serve the purpose as it shows 404 or redirects to particular page.

I have added the following to `/config/application.rb`

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/handle_invalid_percent_encoding.rb"
config.middleware.insert 0, HandleInvalidPercentEncoding
```

And this is my middleware handle_invalid_percent_encoding.rb

> require 'rack'
>
> class HandleInvalidPercentEncoding
>
> ```
>  def initialize(app)
>    @app = app
>  end
>
>  def call(env)
>    request = Rack::Request.new(env.dup)
>    temp = request.params rescue :bad_form_data
>    if temp == :bad_form_data
>      error_response
>    else
>      @app.call(env)
>    end
>  end
>
>  private
>
>  def error_response
>    # serve static html file
>  end
> ```
>
> end

P.S I need to render bad request error only when the argument error is Invalid encoding.